# Set selected item in combobox to "please select..."

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I'd like to add "Please select..." as the first option in my combobox.  See code below - any suggestions?

Regards,
Peter

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", "password"); 
mysql_select_db('mysqldb');

$sql = "SELECT data_id FROM projects";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='data_id '>";
$sql[0] = 'Please select...';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['data_id '] . "'>" . $row['data_id'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace
`$sql[0] = 'Please select...';`
to this
`echo '<option value="" disabled>Please select...</option>';`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace your `$sql[0] = 'Please select...';` line (which by the way does nothing useful whatsoever) by this line:

```
echo "<option selected disabled>Please select...</option>";
```

The *selected* keyword is even optional if this is the first option you specify.